# Use PhP Variable in Vue js component

Tags: php, vuejs3

I am starting to integrate some Vue 3 Components in my existing PhP project.

The code looks like the following example

phpfile.php

```
<?php
//..get some User and Session Data
//.. get some other fancy data from DB
$data = array(
'userData' => $userdata,
'otherData' => $otherData
);
include 'template.php';
?>
```

template.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>Link to vue js CDN</script>
<-- Head stuff -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="vueApp">
<div v-if="isAdmin"> <-- show some Admin things --></div>
<div v-else> <-- show some not Admin things --></div>
</div>
<script src="../vueComponent.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

vueComponent.js

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
    return {
           isAdmin: false,
           }
    },
methods: {

    
},
mounted() {
    
}
})
app.mount('#vueApp')
```

How do i get the $data['userdata'] into the vue component?

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: Pass it as a prop or make it as an API endpoint that the component can call the data from and fill the component data with

Comment: Hi, i dont want to write an extra api to get the same data i already fetched for loading the page in the first place.

So, how do i pass them as pro to the component?
A <?php echo $data['userData']['admin'];?> in the js file wont work

Comment: You cant is why I am saying that, atleast in the context you want

Answer (score 0):

Put the data on the document before calling the component.

```
<script>const data = <?= json_encode($data); ?></script>
<script src="../vueComponent.js"></script>
```

Then pass it to the component:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      isAdmin: data.userData.isAdmin,
    }
  },
...
```

You could also set after like:

```
app.isAdmin = data.userData.isAdmin
```

Comment: imo, vue and php is ugly, rewrite your app using nuxt, then set data in the vuex store though nuxtServerInit

Comment: Thank you! I will try this way.
@Lawrence  I have no experience with nuxt. Im still learning to work with vue to improve my front end and may rebuild the entire project with it. But i will have a look at nuxt.